# Modify QT Defines in .pro file from C++ file

Tags: c++, qt

Sorry, if this question doesn't make any sense but It just came to my mind, I was looking for a solution on this from quite long time but in the end I thought better to check with experts. :)

Below is a scenario:

1. Suppose In myProject.pro file, I have 
         PATH = /home/local/Projects/
   for which I created a QT DEFINE using below:
    DEFINES += PATH =\\"$${PATH}\\"
2. Now, I can use this "PATH" any where in my Project which is based on CPP file. This if perfectly fine.
3. Now, depending upon the input from user, I want to change this "PATH"
   say, PATH can be:
       PATH = /home/local/Projects/TEST1/

   ```
   PATH = /home/local/Projects/TEST2/

           and revert to

   PATH = /home/local/Projects/
   ```

So, that wherever I am using this "PATH" in my project will be changed automatically.

I know this is done at compile time. But came a thought. So wanted to get feedbacks from experts.

Answer (score 0):

What you call a "Qt define" is actually preprocessor macro, which is given to compiler in command line, as opposed to including it into a source code file with #define. you can use it as literal to initialize a global variable with "default" value, which, if not being const, can be changed in code.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach: use a global configuration object that takes the value of the `PATH` literal as the default value for its `path` member. That default value can be then changed by the user:

```
class Configuration {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(Configuration)
  static Configuration * self;
public:
  static Configuration * instance() { return self; }
  Configuration() {
    Q_ASSERT(!self);
    self = this;
  }
  ~Configuration() { self = {}; }

  QString path{PATH};
};

Configuration * Configuration::self;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  Configuration configuration;
  QApplication app{argc, argv};
  ...
  qDebug() << Configuration::instance()->path;
}
```

Whenever you wish to access configuration globally, use the `Configuration::instance()` static method to obtain the instance, then use its `path` member. It will be set to the hardcoded `PATH` by default, but you can change it at any time.

The `Configuration::instance()` implements the same idiom as `QCoreApplication::instance()`: it lets you access a globally unique value, without suffering from the static initialization order fiasco.